# "java.io.IOException" While "Downloading Component" Phase of Installing Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

## Here is the screenshot.

[image: The red text is the exception message.]

#### Note: Please don't answer the question if you yourself are not sure. I'm a neophyte to Android Studio, so it'll only confuse me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Android SDK Manager,

go to "Options" in the "Tools" menu,

check the option `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...".`

Comment: I'm installing Android Studio again. I'll implement your answer as soon as it's done.

Comment: Let's say I download this problematic file separately from " https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip ". Do you happen to know where do I unzip that file?